# Modal Window not showing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

When I make a modal window the content is showing but there no white box surrounding the content. Could someone point me in the right direction.

```
<div class="row">
            <ul>
                <li class="thumbnail col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#ensuite" data-toggle="modal"><img src="img/thumbs/6.jpg" alt="En-suite Bedroom"></a></li>
                <li class="thumbnail col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="img/thumbs/6.jpg" alt="En-suite Bedroom"></a></li>
                <li class="thumbnail col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="img/thumbs/6.jpg" alt="En-suite Bedroom"></a></li>
                <li class="thumbnail col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="img/thumbs/6.jpg" alt="En-suite Bedroom"></a></li>
                <li class="thumbnail col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="img/thumbs/6.jpg" alt="En-suite Bedroom"></a></li>
                <li class="thumbnail col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="img/thumbs/6.jpg" alt="En-suite Bedroom"></a></li>
                <li class="thumbnail col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src="img/thumbs/6.jpg" alt="En-suite Bedroom"></a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

modals

```
  <div id="ensuite" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-dismiss="modal">                </button>
     <h4> En-Suite Room </h4>
        </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="En-Suite Room" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"> Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: totally unrelated: why did you delete that other question? did you find the solution? if so, was it not worth posting in case someone else faces the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your misssing the `modal-content` wrapper

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"></div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The other problem I am also have is that the pictures arent centering in the thumbnail.

Comment: @MatthewWilson Consider [Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint)-ing your HTML in the future; it catches this and other Bootstrap errors.